# Find all instances of a class, create array of a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have some code:

```
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Red">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Blue">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Green">…</div>
```

How do I get all the data-color values into an array that I can compare against?

Suppose the `Active Color` is Red, then the script would say **if active.value == data-color, remove class "hide"**

Comment: Is this two questions? What does the array have to do with finding the instance with the active color?

Comment: I guess nothing @Barmar! I just wasn't sure if you needed an array or not :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  var colors = $('.product-images').toArray().map(function(prod) {
    return $(prod).data('color');
  });
  console.log(colors);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Red">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Blue">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Green">…</div>
```

If you want to use a specific color and remove the hide class for all of the products that have these data-color value, use this:

```js
$(function() {
  var activeValue = 'Red';
  $('.product-images[data-color=' + activeValue + ']').removeClass('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Red">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Blue">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Green">…</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gutelaunetyp ! In the second option, how would you add the class back once there is a new activeValue? went from Red to Blue?

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over each element with the class, and make an array:

```js
var colors = [];
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".product-images.hide");
[].forEach.call(divs, function(elem) {
    colors.push(elem.getAttribute("data-color"));
})
console.log(colors);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Red">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Blue">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Green">…</div>
```

And to answer your second question, to remove the `.hide` class from the correct element:

```js
var activeColor = "Red";
$(`div['data-color'=${activeColor}`).removeClass("hide");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Red">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Blue">…</div>
<div class="product-images hide" data-color="Green">…</div>
```